# "Akcelo": Is this a mistake in the Wells English-Esperanto Dictionary?

Tags: word-usage

The Wells dictionary has the following entry:

> **akcel/o** accelerate; further, promote;

Surely it should be "akceli" if we are talking about a verb? But "akceli" isn't listed. Usually, when a root form can take both a verb and noun ending, it's listed differently, e.g.:

> **akcent/o**, -i accent, stress

Plena Ilustrita Vortaro has both "akceli" (to accelerate) and "akcelo" (acceleration).

Answer (score 6):

It is a mistake, as you noted. As a rule of thumb PIV triumphs over most, especially non-Esperanto, dictionaries.

Most if not all Esperanto dictionaries give as the first entry the form that matches the [*radikokarakteron*](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortfarado), in this case *akceli/i* because the root *akcel/* has a verb-like character. If your dictionary leaves that out, it's a serious error.